# Pivoting with multiple for ins

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have the below table **t1**:

| A | B | C | V |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | V1 |
| A2 | B1 | C2 | V2 |
| A3 | B2 | C1 | V3 |
| A4 | B2 | C2 | V4 |
| A1 | B1 | C1 | V10 |
| A1 | B1 | C2 | V11 |

I would like to obtain the below output:

| A | B1_C1 | B1_C2 | B2_C1 | B2_C2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | V1 | V11 | null | null |
| A2 | null | V2 | null | null |
| A3 | null | null | V3 | null |
| A4 | null | null | null | V4 |

I would like to have the *minimum* of **V** grouping by **A**, being the columns the combinations **B**, **C**

Answer (score 0):

If you know the columns you want, use conditional aggregation:

```
select a,
       max(case when b = 'B1' and c = 'C1' then v end) as b1_c1,
       max(case when b = 'B1' and c = 'C2' then v end) as b1_c2,
       max(case when b = 'B2' and c = 'C1' then v end) as b2_c1,
       max(case when b = 'B2' and c = 'C2' then v end) as b2_c2
from t
group by a;
```

Comment: Actually, I don't know the columns, I need a dynamic way :(

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to make it 'dynamically', but, for `PIVOT`, with a fixed maximal number of columns :

```sql
WITH t1 AS (SELECT 'A1' A , 'B1' B, 'C1' C,  'V1' V FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL SELECT 'A2', 'B1', 'C2', 'V2' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL SELECT 'A3', 'B2', 'C1', 'V3' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL SELECT 'A4', 'B2', 'C2', 'V4' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL SELECT 'A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'V10' FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL SELECT 'A1', 'B1', 'C2', 'V11' FROM DUAL), 
     t2 AS (SELECT t1.A, t1.B||'_'||t1.C col, t1.V
              FROM t1),
     t3 AS (SELECT ROWNUM colnum, col FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t2.col FROM t2 ORDER BY t2.col))       
 SELECT NULL A, 
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 1) col1,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 2) col2,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 3) col3,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 4) col4,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 5) col5,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 6) col6,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 7) col7,
       (SELECT t3.col FROM t3 WHERE colnum = 8) col8
  FROM DUAL
 UNION ALL
SELECT *
  FROM (
SELECT A, MAX(col1_v) col1, MAX(col2_v) col2, MAX(col3_v) col3, MAX(col4_v) col4, 
          MAX(col5_v) col5, MAX(col6_v) col6, MAX(col7_v) col7, MAX(col8_v) col8
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM (SELECT t2.A, t2.V, t3.col, t3.colnum 
                  FROM t2 JOIN t3 ON t3.col = t2.col)
         PIVOT (
           MIN(V) AS V
           FOR colnum IN (1 AS col1, 2 AS col2, 3 AS col3, 4 AS col4, 5 AS col5, 6 AS col6, 7 AS col7, 8 AS col8)
         ) )
  GROUP BY A
  ORDER BY A
)
```

Here for 8 different combinations of B and C max. the first row of the output describes which column has which combination of B and C, the following rows are your expected results. You can adapt it with the max number of possible combinations of B and C, just add the columns.

**Warning:** If the number of B and C combinations exceed the fixed number of columns, the query **will run** but the output will be **limited** to number of combination allowed by the current number of columns.

The [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=395e02450a0c6547c870f11be456f7c6) if you want to test it.

Comment: It is also possible to have dynamic number of columns and dynamic naming for them through [Oracle polymorphic functions](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/how-to-dynamically-change-the-columns-in-a-sql-query), but it requires writing PLSQL code  in your db.

Comment: Or [SQL macros](https://oracle-base.com/articles/21c/sql-macros-21c#table-expressions) too (Thanks @WilliamRobertson for the idea) .

Answer (score 0):

You principally need to concatenate `b` and `c` columns, and then pivot by those columns while grouping them by the column `a` such as

```
WITH t2 AS
(
SELECT b||'_'||c AS bc, a, v
  FROM t1
)
SELECT a,
       MIN(DECODE(bc,'B1_C1',v)) AS b1_c1,
       MIN(DECODE(bc,'B1_C2',v)) AS b1_c2,
       MIN(DECODE(bc,'B2_C1',v)) AS b2_c1,
       MIN(DECODE(bc,'B2_C2',v)) AS b2_c2
  FROM t2 
 GROUP BY a 
 ORDER BY a
```

You can create such a stored function, which returns `SYS_REFCURSOR` type result, by using the select statement above as the main query along with an auxiliary query to generate the aggregated conditionals in order to accomplish this dynamically ;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION Get_Pivoted_Values RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_cols      VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN 
  SELECT LISTAGG( 'MIN(DECODE(bc,'''||bc||''',v)) AS '||bc , ',' ) 
          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY bc )        
    INTO v_cols
    FROM ( SELECT b||'_'||c AS bc
             FROM t1
            GROUP BY b||'_'||c
            ORDER BY bc ); 

  v_sql :='WITH t2 AS
           (
            SELECT b||''_''||c AS bc, t.*
              FROM t1
           )
           SELECT a,'|| v_cols ||'
             FROM t2 
            GROUP BY a 
            ORDER BY a';            

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
/
```

Then run the below code ;

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := Get_Pivoted_Values;
PRINT rc
```

from *SQL Developer*'s Command Line in order to see the expected result set.